# Is there relationship (and translation) between Link Grammars and Combinatory Categorial Grammars?

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar, software

Is there relationship (and translation) between Link Grammars and Combinatory Categorial Grammars? Link Grammars have very unusual parse structure - links between words, but CCGs have parse trees. Some connections are mentioned in 
 https://files.ifi.uzh.ch/cl/gschneid/papers/FINALSgeroldschneider-latl.pdf

In this informal discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opencog/ATnOqdpDDdM is mentioned that Link Grammars can be mapped to CCGs? Is it really possible.

It would be nice to have such mapping. There has already been done great work with Link Grammars and translation to CCGs would allow to attach automated inference systems for the natural language understanding and automatic deduction on natural language texts.